# SAP UI5 table filterProperty Suggest

Tags: sapui5, hana

[image: same like image.]i am new in SAP UI5. i created a table having 2 columns and applied sort and filter property all are working fine. but now i want some suggest list should appear while user is giving input in filter box. please help below is my code.

`var    oTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
                editable : false,
                width : "auto",
                visibleRowCount : 6
            });
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                    text : "Product Name"
                }),
                template : new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value",
                        "PNAME"),
                enabled : false,
                editable : false,
                sortProperty : "PNAME",
                filterProperty : "PNAME",
                display : "none",
                width : "auto"
            }));
oTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({
                    text : "Region Name"
                }),
                template : new sap.ui.commons.TextField().bindProperty("value",
                        "RNAME"),
                enabled : false,
                editable : false,
                sortProperty : "RNAME",
                filterProperty : "RNAME",
                display : "none",
                width : "auto"
            }));`

Answer (score 0):

TextField is deprecated since 1.38. Instead, use the sap.m.Input control.
Input control has suggestion functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but here i used that text just for columns name which  i want to display in table. and filterProperty : "RNAME" this helps for filtering.so i want suggestion list while giving first char of input in  filter-box .